# SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file' if in root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

My `DatabaseContext` has:

```
string physicalPath = "Filename=" + Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data"), "Database.db");
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(physicalPath);
```

My `Startup` has:

```
using (var client = new DatabaseContext())
{
   client.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

It works perfectly with `"D:\\Database.db"` but that's not very portable so I need to use its own directories.

Has anyone any idea?

**Update**: 
I tried again with a tutorial [here](https://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/6941-an-aspnet-core-mvc-app-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework)  and got same error in an exception page.

> "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SqliteException: SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(int rc,
>   sqlite3 db)"

Update: I get "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\test.txt' is denied.'" when I try

> string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
>   "test.txt");
>
> using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) { Byte[] info = new
>   UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file."); // Add
>   some information to the file. fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length); }

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following to construct the path that points to your DB file?:

```
// Gets the current path (executing assembly)
string currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
// Your DB filename    
string dbFileName = "stuff.db"; 
// Creates a full path that contains your DB file
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(currentPath, dbFileName);
```

Do note that you will need to include the following `using` statements in your `DatabaseContext`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: note that this ends looking inside the bin folder for the database

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your Database under **App_Data** folder. All the SQLite required **dll** need to be in **bin** folder. Also the `SQLite.Interop.dll` need to be in **x64 and x86** folder under bin.